# How to log data of a call

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I want to log data of asterisk command line. But the criteria is I want log data for calls separately, i.e. I want to log data for each call in separate file.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I log all data into one file. If I want to review one call, I filter the log file for this file. You can do this very easy with grep: `grep ID LOGLEVEL`. Take a look at the logger.conf manual: http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/Monitoring_id264504.html

Comment: question: do you use CDR? if not activate it: http://clients.stabiliservers.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=9

Comment: I know this thing, it gets cumbersome for me to keep a track each ID. Rather what I want to do is, I have an my_gen_ID which is easy to track for me, with this my_gen_ID I will track that asterisk_gen_ID thread and will log entire data in file my_gen_ID.txt. If I do it that way which you are defining, I will need another mapping for  my_gen_ID and asterisk_gen_ID - which I want to avoid. So if someone complaints about any issue I can straightaway look for my_gen_ID.txt and see what happened in that call. "Someone" has this my_gen_ID when he/she calls.

Comment: I hope you are not upset that I write here without answering your orinal question (I don't know if it is possible. I never saw somebody doing this log seperation). Perhaps it's possible for you to use external analyzer? There are a few hundred free analyzer tools for CDR log. e.g.: https://code.google.com/p/asterisk-cdr-viewer/ . To analyze the logger file you can use plugins for nagios (if you have setup a nagios in your network): https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Nagios-Log-Server/Dashboards/Asterisk-Log-Analyzer/details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case there is no inbuild feature in asterisk to do this, here is a bash solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "0" >/tmp/numberoflines
IFS=''
pathToLogFile = /path/to/log/file
while [ 1 ]
do
    NUMBER=$(cat /tmp/numberoflines)
    LINECOUNT=$(wc -l < $pathToLogFile)
    DIFFERENCE=$(($LINECOUNT-$NUMBER))

    if [ $DIFFERENCE != 0 ]; then
        lines=($(tail -n $DIFFERENCE $pathToLogFile))
        for line in $lines; do
            callID = `expr "$line" : 'CALLID_REGEX (see below)'`
            $(echo "$line" >> /path/to/log/directory/$callID)
        done
    fi

sleep 5;
echo "$LINECOUNT" >/tmp/numberoflines
done
```

**untested**

it should be used to get ab idea to solve this problem.

the regular expression: normaly: `/\[(C\d{8})\]/`. sadly I don't know the syntax in bash. I'm sorry. you have to convert it by yourself into bash-syntax.

---

The idea is: remember the last line in the logfile that was processed by the bash script. check the line count of the log file. if there are more lines then the remembered line: walk through the new lines and extract the call id at the beginning of each line (format: C******** (* are numbers). in words: a C followed by a number with 8 digits). now append the whole line at the end of a log file. the name of the file is the extracted callid.

---

**EDIT** Information about the call id (don't mistake it with the caller id): https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Unique+Call-ID+Logging

Comment: Thanks man for providing a different perspective :). I can make that work